# How to access methods of an arbitrary view helper by an arbitrary erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, helper

By convention, Rails only "attaches" the view helper which corresponds to the controller the erb file is called of.

How can I access a view helper's methods of an arbitrary view helper in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do that, something is wrong with the organization of your code. Instead, move the helper methods that both of your views need into a common module, and include that module in both.

For example, if you have:

```
module ApplesHelper
  def flavor_of(fruit)
  end
end
```

and you want /bananas views to have access to the `flavor_of` method, then do this:

```
module Flavored
  def flavor_of(fruit)
    # ...
  end
end

module ApplesHelper
  include Flavored
end

module BananasHelper
  include Flavored
end
```

---

**Update:** I realized that I didn't actually answer the original question directly. The way to include another helper in a view is with `helper`:

```
class BananasController ...
  helper ApplesHelper
end
```

Now all /bananas view also have the ApplesHelper methods available to them.

Comment: Refactoring out the code is a good point and solves problem... +1

Comment: Updated to actually answer the question, though I still recommend refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well the question, you have to define your method helper with:

```
module ControllerHelper
   def function_you_have_to_call
      some_code_here
   end
end
```

When you want to call your method helper by the *.erb file, you have to insert this in the view:

```
<% function_you_have_to_call %>
```

If your method has a return value and you want to store it in an local variable defined in your view, try:

```
<% value_you_want = function_you_have_to_call %>
```

Remember the code included by `<% %>` is only interpreted by ruby and not shown by view. In this case you have to use code included by `<%= %>`.

Now you can access `value_you_want` and maybe use for statements.

Comment: Yes, thats the default behaviour of Rails. Given your example, a view in /views/Controller has only access to methods defined ControllerHelper. I want to call a method of OtherControllerHelper from a view in /views/Controller...

Comment: @Scholle Sorry I forgot to insert the include in another controller. Now I realized that I didn't answer correctly!